# How to calculate Drain Value with Reckless Spellcasting

Tags: spells, shadowrun-sr5

If I cast Punch with Force 1 and Reckless Spellcasting, how much Drain do I have to resist? Is the minimum of 2 Drain considered before the +3 or after?

- Option 1: **Drain minimum first**, MAX (2, (1 - 6)) -> 2 + 3 = 5
- Option 2: **Reckless +3 first**, MAX(2, (1 + 3 - 6) -> 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The minimum drain is applied last

When you cast a spell using the *Reckless Spellcasting* option, you take an extra drain value (DV) for casting that spell (CRB, p.281):

> Step 4: Cast Spell - Reckless Spellcasting
>
> it lets you cast a spell as a Simple Action instead of a Complex Action, but with an added **+3 Drain Value**.

However, note that the *minimum drain* is applied on step 6, after all drain calculations were done (CRB, p.281):

> Step 6: Resist Drain
>
> the Drain Value is determined using the Force and the listed calculation, but can never be lower than 2

Since you apply the extra drain on *Step 4*, it adjusts the spell's DV before you have to check if the drain is lower than 2 DV on *Step 6*.

### Missions FAQ

The [Missions FAQ](https://forums.shadowruntabletop.com/index.php?topic=27730.0) also has an entry on this subject:

> *Does the +3 Drain Value from Reckless Spellcasting apply before or after the minimum Drain Value of 2 kicks in?*
>
> You calculate all Drain modifiers at the same time. Thus if you were recklessly casting a Force 2 spell that normally had a drain value of F – 4, the drain would be modified to F – 1, so the drain value would still be 2.